# How to replace 2 consecutive lines after Match with Sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Is there a way to replace the following two lines after a match is found using sed?

I have a file

```
#ABC
oneSize=bar
twoSize=bar
threeSize=foo
```

But I would like to replace the two immediate lines once the pattern `#ABC` is matched so that it becomes

```
#ABC
oneSize=foo
twoSize=foo
threeSize=foo
```

I'm able to do
`gsed '/^#ABC/{n;s/Size=bar/Size=foo/}' file`

But it only changes the line `twoSize` not `oneSize`

Is there a way to get it to change both oneSize and twoSize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gnu and some other sed versions allow you to grab a range using relative number so you can simply use:

```sh
sed -E '/^#ABC$/,+2 s/(Size=)bar/\1foo/' file
#ABC
oneSize=foo
twoSize=foo
threeSize=foo
```

**Command details:**

- `/^#ABC$/,+2` Match range from pattern `#ABC` to next 2 lines
- `s/(Size=)bar/\1foo/`: Match `Size=bar` and replace with `Size=foo`, using a capture group to avoid repeat of same String in search and substitution

---

You may also consider `awk` to avoid repeating pattern and replacements N times if you have to replace N lines after matching pattern:

```sh
awk 'n-- {sub(/Size=bar/, "Size=foo")} /^#ABC$/ {n=2} 1' file

#ABC
oneSize=foo
twoSize=foo
threeSize=foo
```

Answer (score 5):

You can repeat the commands:

```sh
gsed '/^#ABC/{n;s/Size=bar/Size=foo/;n;s/Size=bar/Size=foo/}' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/G8EMh2).

The [`n` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) "*prints the pattern space, then, regardless, replace the pattern space with the next line of input. If there is no more input then sed exits without processing any more commands.*"

So, the first time it is used, you replace on the first line after line starting with `#ABC`, then you replace on the second line below that one.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`, the loop will break when `Size=bar` is no longer found therefore replacing the first 2 lines after the match.

```
$ sed '/^#ABC/{:l;n;s/Size=bar/Size=foo/;tl}' input_file
#ABC
oneSize=foo
twoSize=foo
threeSize=foo
```

Comment: `:l` - set label "l", `n` - get next line, `s///` - replace, `tl` - jump to label "l" if there was a successful replacement with `s///`

Answer (score 0):

Using sed -z

```
sed -z 's/#ABC\noneSize=bar\ntwoSize=bar/#ABC\noneSize=foo\ntwoSize=foo/' file.txt
#ABC
oneSize=foo
twoSize=foo
threeSize=foo
```

Or

```
sed -E -z 's/#ABC\n(.*)bar\n(.*)bar/#ABC\n\1foo\n\2foo/' file.txt
```